# apt get update errors - how to fix them

Tags: apt

I have been unable to run apt get update command properly due to many errors that seem to suggest some repositories are unavailable. I tried 'apt-get clean' but it did not help. I have the following message (Ubuntu 18.04)

```
Err:13 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic amd64 Contents (deb)                                        
  File has unexpected size (39528051 != 92769273). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 2001:67c:1360:8001::23 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:92769273 [weak]
   - SHA256:5b4dd447bb35deb5a446cef9b30cbc78dde20bd58598bee8e9744c97c370e667
   - SHA1:542e69afb40e026121a9d9ff31ed5649486d73cb [weak]
   - MD5Sum:f1ffee77dbd97765067212ecec7a977a [weak]
  Release file created at: Thu, 23 Jul 2020 07:19:14 +0000
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                
Get:15 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic i386 Contents (deb) [56.1 MB]                                   
Err:15 http://uk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic i386 Contents (deb)                                             
  
Err:17 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu eoan-cran35/ Release                                          
  404  Not Found [IP: 2600:9000:2131:9000:6:c2d3:f940:93a1 443]
Hit:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thopiekar/miraclecast/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/avidemux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:11 https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 51716619E084DAB9 Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu eoan-cran35/ Release' no longer has a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 51716619E084DAB9 Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>
```

Could I ask what I should do to fix this please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Comment: *eoan* or 19.10 is EOL and after releases go EOL, many repositories are deleted. if you check your *eoan* source you'll note they only provide packages for supported releases (your *eoan* isn't supported)

Comment: Excuse my lack of linux knowledge... I tried 'sudo ppa-purge https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu eoan-cran35/', but i get an error on this command - E: The repository 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu eoan-cran35/ Release' no longer has a Release file.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/ InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 51716619E084DAB9 Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>
Warning:...